# How to specify variant tau?

Tags: symbols, greek

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

How can I get the "hooked" form of lowercase tau (see below) to show in posts in SE (Math, Theoretical CS, etc.)?

[image: tau]

P.S. I tried the "obvious" `\vartau`, but no dice.

Comment: Have you seen it in any post? If so, which one? How about you edit the post and see what *they* used? There are options like `\uptau` and `\tauup`, both of which require additional fonts/packages which MathJax don't support natively.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For such concerns, have a look at [Detexify²](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), which will try to recognice a symbol you drew:

---

[image]

---

As you can see, it totally agrees with **Mico**.

You can also have a look at the following question: [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol) It deals with the common problem of finding the code for a certain symbol.

Answer (score 16):

You're so close. Try loading the `upgreek` package and then typing `\uptau`.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `upgreek` package. However, the `\uptau` symbol is upright. Is it somehow possible to get the italicized version of the same symbol? I don't want the regular `\tau`.